# unable to form structure and update the values other than currentTab

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to form the structure like expectedOutput by iterating tabs data and updating the value only if matches mnemonic other than currentTab which is present in tabs data

```js
let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}]}

let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'}

let expectedOutput = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}]}

let newObj = Object.values(tabs).filter((_each)=> {
  return _each.filter((_eachItem)=> {
    if(_eachItem.mnemonic==obj.mnemonic) {
      return _eachItem.value = obj.value
    }
  })
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> updating the value **other than currentTab**

You haven't added any check for this in your code. Since the currentTab is defined by the key, you should get the keys instead of values and filter out the currentTab and modify the rest. Something like this:

```js
let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}]}

let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'}

let expectedOutput = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}]}

Object.keys(tabs)
      .filter(tab => tab != currentTab)
      .flatMap(tab => tabs[tab])
      .filter(data => data.mnemonic == obj.mnemonic)
      .forEach(data => data.value = obj.value);
  

console.log(tabs)
```

If the original data needs to be unmodified, we also need to clone each tab data, otherwise the references will still point to the same object as the original. It can't be written quite as pretty:

```js
let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}]}

let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'}

let expectedOutput = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}]}

let newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tabs).map(([tab,data]) => {
    data = data.map(d => ({...d}));
    if(tab != currentTab) data.filter(d => d.id == obj.id).forEach(d => d.value = obj.value);
    return [tab,data];
  })
);
  
console.log("original",tabs);
console.log("new",newTabs);
```

Comment: @chidananda yes, I will edit accordingly, and note that your original code also modifies the original tabs data - you need to actively clone each object in the structure in order to do this